# Using only Boost.DateTime with errors on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I am using b2.exe to compile Boost.DateTime:

```
.\b2.exe install --with-date_time link=static runtime-link=static
```

It create `bin.v2` directory in `C\:Downloads\boost_1_66_0`, I copy static lib `libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib` from `bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\msvc-14.1\debug\link-static\threadapi-win32\threading-multi` to my project

and copy all of the headers from `C\:Downloads\boost_1_66_0\boost`  to my project

I am try to include `#include "boost/date_time.hpp"` with error

```
error(active)   E1696   cannot open source file "boost/cstdint.hpp" ConsoleApplication1 c : \Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\include\boost\date_time\posix_time\posix_time_config.hpp  14
Error(active)   E1696   cannot open source file "boost/config/no_tr1/cmath.hpp" ConsoleApplication1 c : \Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\include\boost\date_time\posix_time\posix_time_config.hpp  15
Error(active)   E1696   cannot open source file "boost/cstdint.hpp" ConsoleApplication1 c : \Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\include\boost\date_time\time_duration.hpp 12
Error(active)   E1696   cannot open source file "boost/operators.hpp"   ConsoleApplication1 c : \Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\include\boost\date_time\time_duration.hpp 13
Error(active)   E1696   cannot open source file "boost/static_assert.hpp"   ConsoleApplication1 c : \Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\include\boost\date_time\time_duration.hpp 14
Error(active)   E0169   expected a declaration  ConsoleApplication1 c : \Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\include\boost\date_time\time_duration.hpp 289
Error(active)   E1696   cannot open source file "boost/cstdint.hpp" ConsoleApplication1 c : \Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\include\boost\date_time\time_resolution_traits.hpp    13
Error(active)   E0020   identifier "time_resolution_traits_adapted32_impl" is undefined ConsoleApplication1 c : \Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\include\boost\date_time\time_resolution_traits.hpp    135
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-sgd-x32-1_66.lib' ConsoleApplication1 C : \Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\LINK  1
```

Comment: The missing include files should be self explanatory - it's a common complaint about `boost` that it has a lot of interdependencies. As for the missing library, you didn't copy it to a place on your link path.

Comment: after I copy all of the headers from boost to my project, still problem

Comment: after define #define BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB is compile success

Answer (score 1):

after define #define BOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB is compile success

Comment: It's two years later, but you just solved 2 hours of headaches. Thanks